# How can I move certain nodes near coords in a bar chart depending on their value?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I want to write the values of bars in a bar chart (ybar) inside each bar, except for when there is not enough space. In that case, I want to write the value above the bar.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}% write data file to make make MWE self contained 
\begin{filecontents*}{test.txt}
aa  bb  cc  dd
A   7304.91 12713.3 13748.95    
B   13628.96    14912.36    19002.29
C   15158.99    29120.11    31566.62
D   23459.77    26894.28    39129.52
E   23095.17    45234.5 50103.37
F   35540.84    38491.29    55900.97
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{test.txt}
\datatable
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
nodes near coords,
every node near coord/.append style={xshift=0.05cm,rotate=90,anchor=east,/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=2},
bar width= 0.4cm,
/pgf/number format/.cd,
use comma,
width=0.9\textwidth,
height=7cm,
ymajorgrids,   
xtick={data},
scaled y ticks = false,
xticklabels from table={\datatable}{aa},
ymin=0,ymax=60000,
enlarge x limits = 0.1,
]
\addplot[fill=black!20] table [y=bb,x expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot[fill=white] table [y=cc,x expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot[fill=black!10] table [y=dd,x expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

What I would like now is for the values of the 1st to 5th and 7th bar to be written above the bars, not inside them. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

The following measures the width of the nodes and make its anchor depend on whether it fits into the bar or not.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}% write data file to make make MWE self contained 
\begin{filecontents*}{test.txt}
aa  bb  cc  dd
A   7304.91 12713.3 13748.95    
B   13628.96    14912.36    19002.29
C   15158.99    29120.11    31566.62
D   23459.77    26894.28    39129.52
E   23095.17    45234.5 50103.37
F   35540.84    38491.29    55900.97
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{test.txt}
\datatable
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
nodes near coords,
node near coords style={xshift=0.05cm,
/utils/exec={\setbox0\hbox{\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}
\pgfmathfloattomacro{\pgfplotspointmeta}{\F}{\M}{\E}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myanchor}{ifthenelse(\M*pow(10,\E-3)*2-\the\wd0>0,"east","west")}
%\typeout{\M,\E,\the\wd0,\mysign,\myanchor}
},
rotate=90,anchor=\myanchor,
/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=2},
bar width= 0.4cm,
/pgf/number format/.cd,
use comma,
width=0.9\textwidth,
height=7cm,
ymajorgrids,   
xtick={data},
scaled y ticks = false,
xticklabels from table={\datatable}{aa},
ymin=0,ymax=60000,
enlarge x limits = 0.1,
]
\addplot[fill=black!20] table [y=bb,x expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot[fill=white] table [y=cc,x expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot[fill=black!10] table [y=dd,x expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this comparison `\M*pow(10,\E-3)*2-\the\wd0>0` here is (in a way) chosen by hand because during the run it is not yet known that one unit is in pt. One could compute it but then this would require an iteration.

**OLDER ANSWER**: You could introduce a shift (`xshift` since we are doing it after `rotate=90`) for the nodes near coordinates. If I understand you correctly, this is different for different plots so we need to add it to each `\addplot` separately.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}% write data file to make make MWE self contained 
\begin{filecontents*}{test.txt}
aa  bb  cc  dd
A   7304.91 12713.3 13748.95    
B   13628.96    14912.36    19002.29
C   15158.99    29120.11    31566.62
D   23459.77    26894.28    39129.52
E   23095.17    45234.5 50103.37
F   35540.84    38491.29    55900.97
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{test.txt}
\datatable
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
nodes near coords,
node near coords style={xshift=0.05cm,
rotate=90,anchor=east,
/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=2},
bar width= 0.4cm,
/pgf/number format/.cd,
use comma,
width=0.9\textwidth,
height=7cm,
ymajorgrids,   
xtick={data},
scaled y ticks = false,
xticklabels from table={\datatable}{aa},
ymin=0,ymax=60000,
enlarge x limits = 0.1,
]
\addplot[fill=black!20,
every node near coord/.append style={/tikz/xshift={
ifthenelse(\coordindex<3,1,0)*1.6cm}}
] table [y=bb,x expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot[fill=white,
every node near coord/.append style={/tikz/xshift={
ifthenelse(\coordindex<3,1,0)*1.6cm}}] table [y=cc,x expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot[fill=black!10,
every node near coord/.append style={/tikz/xshift={
ifthenelse(\coordindex<2,1,0)*1.6cm}}] table [y=dd,x expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million!